# Rails 4: has_many through association not working - tricky association key handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

UPDATED QUESTION:

NOTE: Org table in remote db (likely source of problem)

A has_may through association is not working and cannot figure out why. Hoping someone can identify the problem.

Company model (companies table in local db)

```
has_many :locations, class_name: "Org", primary_key: :name, foreign_key: :c_name
has_many :reviews, through: :locations
```

Org model **(orgs table in remote db, using establish_connection to reach it)**

```
belongs_to :company, primary_key: :name, foreign_key: :c_name
has_many :reviews, primary_key: :key, foreign_key: :location_id
```

Review model (reviews table in local db)

I would like to do:

```
company.reviews.count
```

But it fails as it is trying to reach orgs table on local db and, of course, can't find it.
company.locations.count works just fine as expected tho.

Comment: Could you list the attributes of your models that are relevant to this? (c_name, primary, etc)

Comment: @Austio: Company.name ties to Org.c_name. Org.key (primary) ties to Review.location_id. Not sure if any other attributes come into play. As the error notes, orgs table does not have a location_id column. I am trying to understand why it is trying to use it. I must also mention that the orgs table lives in separate db from companies and reviews tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the org model's first belongs_to line to:

```
belongs_to :c_name, class_name: 'Company'
```

Comment: sorry, this makes no sense to me. ?

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
has_many :reviews, through: :locations, class_name: "Org"
```

to

```
has_many :reviews, through: :locations
```

Or if model's class is not `Review`, then

```
has_many :reviews, through: :locations, class_name: "MyAwesomeReviewModelClass"
```

Comment: updated my question to clarify better. I did try what you say but tries to reach orgs table in local db instead of remote.